# Undecidable statement that doesn't involve infinity

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

All statements independent of ZFC I'm aware of involve infinity.

Do we know any statement independent of ZFC of the form $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: P(n)$ where $P(n)$ is disprovable if false? (In other words, an independent statement that could be disprovable by a counterexample).

If not, can we show that such a statement must exist? Can there be a consistent logical system in which such a statement cannot exist?

Comment: This is a famous solved problem. The statement "ZFC is consistent"  is expressible in ZFC and unprovable in ZFC if the statement is true - that is the conclusion of Godel's incompleteness theorem. The statement is easy to disprove if false - just present the formal proof of any contradiction from the ZFC axioms.

Comment: And the statement "ZFC is consistent" IS a statement of the desired form: "For all natural numbers $n$, $n$ is not the code of a ZFC proof of the formula 0 = 1"

Comment: "Can there be a consistent logical system in which such a statement cannot exist?"  Godel's theorem (which always produces undecidable statements of the very simple sort you describe) does hold for a very general class of sufficiently strong formal systems. However, there are systems that are complete, even some quite natural ones. For example, Presberger arithmetic, and the theory of real closed fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, "ZFC is consistent" is itself such a statement (once properly expressed in the language of set theory). We can do even better, though: the [MRDP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set) (or rather, its proof) shows that (assuming ZFC is consistent) there is a Diophantine equation $P$ with no solutions, which ZFC cannot prove has no solutions. This is about as concrete as it gets!

So no, incompleteness manifests at even the most concrete levels of mathematical propositions.

---

EDIT: Expanding a bit on my claim above:

The MRDP theorem does *not* directly imply my claim above - hence my parenthetical comment "**or rather, its proof**."

The proof of the MRDP theorem "goes through in PA" in a precise sense:

> $(*)\quad$ For any specific $\Sigma_1$ sentence $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic, we get a specific Diophantine equation $\mathcal{E}_\varphi$ such that **PA proves that** $\mathcal{E}_\varphi$ has a solution iff $\varphi$ is true.

Now take $\varphi$ to be "ZFC is inconsistent." Under reasonable assumptions - namely, the $\Sigma_1$-soundness of PA and the consistency of ZFC - we get the following:

- $\mathcal{E}_\varphi$ has no solutions (since ZFC is consistent), and hence PA (being $\Sigma_1$-sound) doesn't prove that $\mathcal{E}_\varphi$ does have a solution.
- On the other hand we clearly can't have PA prove that $\mathcal{E}_\varphi$ does have a solution, since then PA would prove the consistency of ZFC and hence be inconsistent (and this contradicts $\Sigma_1$-soundness, to put it mildly).

So the sentence "$\mathcal{E}_\varphi$ has no solution" is (under the reasonable assumptions above) true yet undecidable in PA.

*The proof of $(*)$ is not easy (it consists of carefully analyzing the proof of the MRDP theorem, which is quite nontrivial) so I'm not going to go into it here. If one is interested, a separate question on the topic would be reasonable and I might answer it if I find the time; as far as I can tell this hasn't been asked at MSE before.*

Comment: Not sure about the truth of this statement. The MRDP theorem states that any diophantine equation corresponds to a recursively enumerable set, and it is a subset of the diophantine equations that correspond to the recursively enumerable sets that are of infinite cardinality which cannot be proven to have no solution. Your counterexample is not really a counterexample.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich And that's why I was careful to say "**(or rather, its proof)**" - the result I've stated in my answer isn't a direct consequence of the MRDP theorem, but does follow from the argument used to prove the MRDP theorem. Specifically, the proof of the MRDP theorem "goes through in PA," and we get for any specific $e\in\mathbb{N}$ a Diophantine equation $\mathcal{E}_e$ such that **PA proves that** $\mathcal{E}_e$ has a solution iff the $e$th $\Sigma_1$ sentence in the language of arithmetic is true. Now take the index $e$ of the sentence "There is a contradiction in ZFC." (cont'd)

Comment: Clearly (hopefully!) $\mathcal{E}_e$ has no solution, and thus PA (hopefully!) can't prove that $\mathcal{E}_e$ has a solution; on the other hand, if PA proved that $\\mathcal{E}_e$ has no solutions, we'd have that PA proves Con(ZFC), and this can't (hopefully!) happen. So the answer I've given is correct.

Comment: sorry, but your response made me cross-eyed.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich What part of it don't you understand? (And if you don't understand it, why are you confident that my answer is incorrect?)

Comment: I never said that I was confident. My first words were "not sure about the truth of this statement."

Comment: @TomislavOstojich Well, you were confident enough to downvote ...

Comment: "this answer is not useful."

Comment: @TomislavOstojich How precisely wasn't it useful? You not having the background to understand it doesn't make it not useful - there are lots of answers I don't understand which I don't downvote, since I recognize I lack the background to follow them.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich I've expanded my answer to clarify how we get the result. This answer *cannot* feasibly be made fully self-contained since the proof of $(*)$ is rather long; if you're interested, ask a separate question about it. Regardless, I find the claim that my answer is not useful to be quite rude under the circumstances.